# Cannot retrieve value from post request with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I just wrote my first Ajax request but it doesn't work. It needs to update when a new value in the drop-down list is selected.

This is my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function ajaxLoaded(response) {
    $('#performanceResults').html(response);
}
function doRequest() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "results.php",
        type: 'POST',
        success: ajaxLoaded
    });
}
$('#performance').change(doRequest);
});
```

and this is how I retrieve the q part (which doesn't work):

```
public function getResults() {
    $intCase = intval ( $_POST ['q'] );

    var_dump ( $intCase );

    if ($intCase == 1 or $intCase == 2 ) {
        if ($intCase == 1) {
            $strSql = 'select bidder_id, won, lost, fillrate, costs, cost_auction from result_bidder where tagload = ( select max(tagload) from result_bidder) order by cost_auction asc limit 1';
        }
        if ($intCase == 2) {
            $strSql = 'select bidder_id, won, lost, fillrate, costs, cost_auction from result_bidder where tagload = ( select max( tagload ) from result_bidder ) order by fillrate asc limit 1';
        }

        $arrBestPerformer = $objDatabase->queryresult ( $strSql );
        echo "<table border='1'>
        <tr>
        <th>bidder_id</th>
        <th>won</th>
        <th>lost</th>
        <th>fillrate</th>
        <th>costs</th>
        <th>cost_auction</th>
        </tr>";

        while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array ( $arrBestPerformer ) ) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row ['bidder_id'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row ['won'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row ['lost'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row ['fillrate'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row ['costs'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row ['cost_auction'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
}
```

My Form:
      public function SelectPerformanceIndicator() {

```
  $this->getResults ();

  $str = '<form >';
  $str .= 'Select your performance indicator<br>';
  $str .= '<select id = "performance">';
  $str .= '<option value = "">Select Performance Indicator</option>';
  $str .= '<option value = "1">Cost per auction  </option>';
  $str .= '<option value = "2">Fillrate </option>';
  $str .= '</select>';
  $str .= '</form>';
  $str .= '<br>';
  $str .= '<div id="performanceResults">';

  return $str;
}
```

Comment: just echo $_POST['q']; You're not returning anything right now

Comment: Is this 1 liner your complete PHP script?

Comment: @GaijinJim I know. How do I return values with Ajax?

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER No it is not. Just a form and mysql statement comes after this. Nothing special.

Comment: what issue there, any error??, did you try `echo $_POST ['q']`

Comment: Or try a JS framework like `jQuery` it will help you scripting crossbrowser compatible JS and abstract AJAX requests to a very high level. So you can ensure your AJAX request works. Probably your `var` in JS is just empty when you send it?

Comment: I don't know when you run your function showUser(str) but you need to run it at some point. It should echo your $_POST['q'].

Comment: $_POST['q'] is empty @Girish

Comment: @GaijinJim Added code where I called showUser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your POST data string is invalid.

```
xmlhttp.send("q ="+  str);
```

Should be

```
xmlhttp.send("q="+  str);
```

Without the space between `q` and `=`.

And you missed to send the header to tell PHP that it should map the Data sent with the request to the `$_POST` var.

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

So your correct function would be:

```
function showUser(str) {
    if (str=="") {
        document.getElementById("performance").innerHTML="";
        return;
    } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { 
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("performance").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","results.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("q="+  str);
}
```

But again: use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to make your [AJAX requests](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). If you use jQuery you don't have to struggle with errors like this anymore.

Comment: Fixed that, but it still does not work. Thanks for spotting that error though!

Comment: Again: use [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) to handle your AJAX requests. It's a lot easier and crossbrowser compatible. [See here how AJAX works with jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer. I fixed it the header part, but it still does not work. Does it help if I post the php functions?

Comment: It would help if you would use jQuery to do AJAX stuff!

Comment: Used jQuery. But now it calls my front-end two times instead of just showing the table.

Comment: What's your "front-end"?

Comment: The total results of a run.

Comment: Open a new question if you now try to do it with a jQuery based solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have added space in query string, `"q ="` this is not behaving as `q` key in `$_POST` variable, 
remove space between `key` and `=`

```
xmlhttp.send("q ="+  str);
```

to

```
xmlhttp.send("q="+  str);
```

**Update Answer:** AJax `POST` will be worked when request have `Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header.
please add Header before `send` method

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

`OR`
you can send request by `GET` method without header

Comment: Fixed that, but it still does not work. Thanks for spotting that error though!